# How Foreground Service (different process / same process) behaves when Android is low on memory

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-memory

If `Service` is running in different process (through “`:name`” inside manifest) with a foreground flag. On the occasion when System would like to free some memory.. (imagine heavy ui, user pressing Home and navigating to other heavy app)

1. will it kill just the main process for this app to free resources? (obviously leaving service process intact) and then restart `just` the main process when user navigates back to app.
2. If Service would be running in the same process, would it release all resources like activities except foreground service? or whole process (with heavy ui) in this case would be considered as foreground therefore consuming a lot of memory and not being nice to user phone

P.S

I understand no guarantees for foreground service.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

I understand android design of killing processes instantly
(which kind of answers 2nd question, but want to be sure)

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html

Comment: Small note regarding (2): I started a foreground service from myActivity. Even if I called finish() on myActivity, which eventually resulted in a call to onDestroy() on the activity, the foreground service was still running (unless I explicitly stopped it in onDestroy).

Answer (score 1):

1. If the main process in not in foreground, it will be killed and restarted when required. Foreground service may also be killed if required but not before all background processes are killed. Foreground service will be restarted as soon as memeory become available again.
2. Yes, it will release all resources and try to leave the service running. Service may also be killed if the entire process needs to be terminated. Process will be restarted with only the service running.